# Consider the operator $V f(x)=\int_x^1 f(t) \mathrm{d}t$ of $C^0([0,1])$ in itself. Compute its norm and determine its image.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

> Consider the operator $V f(x)=\int_x^1 f(t) \mathrm{d}t$  of
> $C^0([0,1])$ in itself. Compute its norm and determine its image, i.e.
> $\operatorname{Im}(V)$.

Start with the norm
\begin{equation}
|Vf(x)| = | \int_x^1 f(t) dt|= |\int_0^1 \mathbb{1}_{[x,1]}f(t)dt| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}. 
\end{equation}
Thus $\| V\| \leq 1.$ Is this everything I have to show?

Then for the image I don't have an idea how to proceed. The definition of the image of the operator is given by $\operatorname{Im}(V) = \{ Vf | f \in C^0([0,1]) \}$.

**My attempt:** I want to show that $\operatorname{Im}(V) =  \{ f \in C^0([0,1]) | f(1) = 0 \} $. To show this, I have to show the two inclusions.
Start with

- $\{ f \in C^0([0,1]) | f(1) = 0 \} \subset \operatorname{Im}(V)$:

Let's choose a function $g$ that is differentiable and such that $g(1)=0$, then we see that $\operatorname{V}g' = -g$, thus $-\operatorname{V}g' = g$. We have show that $g \in \operatorname{Im}(V)$.

- $\operatorname{Im}(V) \subset \{ f \in C^0([0,1]) | f(1) = 0 \}$

If we take $h \in \operatorname{Im}(V)$, then there exists $f \in C^0([0,1])$ such that $\int_x^1 f(t) \mathrm{d}t = h(x)$. If we take $f = (-h')$, we get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{V}f = h &\Leftrightarrow \int_x^1 f(t) dt = h(x)\\
 &\Leftrightarrow  \int_x^1 (-h'(t)) dt = h(x) \\
 &\Leftrightarrow  -h(1) + h(x) = h(x) \\
 &\Leftrightarrow  h(1) = 0
\end{align}
Thus $h\in \{ f \in C^0([0,1]) | f(1) = 0 \}$.

Comment: You found un upper bound for the norm of $V$, Now prove that $\|V\|=1$. As for the image, the definite integral of a continuous function is not only continuous, but also...

Comment: That's not the definition of the image. It's $\text{Im}(V) = \{Vf \mid f \in C^0([0,1])\}$.

Comment: The image consists of all continuously differentiable functions vanishing at $1$. Use the constant function $1$ to show that $\|V\|\geq 1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm How did you find this?

Comment: You have been given plenty of hints. Now you can show some effort to use the hints.

Comment: @geetha290krm I will. But with the solution I know that all that I have to show are the two inclusions of $\operatorname{Im} V=\left\{f \in C^0([0,1]) ; f(1)=0\right\}$. This will not help me to understand how I can find the definition of the image myself next time. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Alessandro differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost fine. Note that you did not actually prove that
$$\mbox{Im }V= \left\{ f \in C^0([0,1]) | f(1)=0\right\}$$
but instead you proved that
$$\mbox{Im }V= \left\{ f \in C^1([0,1]) | f(1)=0\right\}$$
because for the first inclusion which you showed the continuity (and the existence!) of $g'$ is needed (and in the other inclusion you can also observe that Im $V \subseteq C^1([0,1])$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus).

In addition to that, you still have to show that $||V|| \geq 1$. This is easy since taking $f \equiv 1$ we get
$$||V||\geq \frac{||Vf||_{\infty}}{||f||_{\infty}}=||1-x||_{\infty}=1$$

Comment: Thank you! But I still ask myself how I can see that the  image is $\{ f \in C^0([0,1]) | f(1) = 0 \}$. This is something someone said in the comments but how to determine this myself?

Comment: The general idea is to provide properties of the elements of the image i.e. necessary conditions for a function to be in Im $V$ and try to see if they are also sufficient.

Comment: Hmm ok, I understand your point but I would still not find the definition of the image in this case here..